# Why is writing to a buffer filled with 42 way faster than writing to a buffer of zeros?

Tags: c++, linux, performance, memory-management, malloc

I would expect writes to a `char *` buffer to take the same time regardless of the existing contents of the memory<sup>1</sup>. Wouldn't you?

However, while narrowing down an inconsistency in a benchmark, I came across a case where this apparently isn't true. A buffer which contains all-zeros behaves much differently, performance-wise, from a buffer filled with `42`.

Graphically, this looks like (details below):

[image: Buffer Write Time]

Here's the code I used to produce the above<sup>3</sup>:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

volatile char *sink;

void process(char *buf, size_t len) {
  clock_t start = clock();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i += 678)
    buf[i] = 'z';
  printf("Processing took %lu μs\n",
      1000000UL * (clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  sink = buf;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int total = 0;
  int memset42 = argc > 1 && !strcmp(argv[1], "42");
  for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    char *buf = (char *)malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    if (memset42)
      memset(buf, 42, BUF_SIZE);
    else
      memset(buf,  0, BUF_SIZE);
    process(buf, BUF_SIZE);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile it on my Linux box like:

```
 gcc -O2 buffer_weirdness.cpp -o buffer_weirdness
```

... and when I run the version with a zero buffer, I get:

```
./buffer_weirdness zero
Processing took   12952 μs
Processing took  403522 μs
Processing took  626859 μs
Processing took  626965 μs
Processing took  627109 μs
```

Note the first iteration is *quick*, while the remaining iterations take perhaps **50 times** longer.

When the buffer is first filled with `42`, processing is always fast:

```
./buffer_weirdness 42
Processing took   12892 μs
Processing took   13500 μs
Processing took   13482 μs
Processing took   12965 μs
Processing took   13121 μs
```

The behavior depends on the `BUF_SIZE (1GB in the example above) - larger sizes are more likely to show the issue, and also depends on the current host state. If I leave the host alone for a while, the slow iterations take perhaps 60,000 μs, rather than 600,000 - so 10x faster, but still ~5x slower than the fast processing time. Eventually the times return to the fully slow behavior.

The behavior also depends at least partly on transparent hugepages - if I disable them<sup>2</sup>, the performance on the slow iterations improves by a factor of about 3x, while the fast iterations are unchanged.

A final note is the the *total* runtime for the process is much closer than simply timing the *process* routine (in fact, the zero filled, THP off version is about 2x faster than the others, which are roughly the same).

What's going on here?

---

<sup>1</sup> Outside of some *very* unusual optimization such as the compiler understanding what value the buffer already contained and eliding writes of the same value, which isn't happening here.

<sup>2</sup> `sudo sh -c "echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled"`

<sup>3</sup> It's a distilled version of the original benchmark. Yes, I'm leaking the allocations, get over it - it leads to a more concise example. The original example didn't leak. In fact, when you don't leak the allocations, the behavior changes: probably because `malloc` can just re-use the region for the next allocation, rather than asking the OS for more memory.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, observed behavior most probably compiler/OS/hardware specific

Comment: I can't reproduce the magnitude of the timings; I get 0-1µs for 0 or 42.

Comment: @Slava - I reproduced it on a few different Linux boxes, but it did seem related to the amount of physical memory - on systems with more RAM, I either needed to increase `BUF_SIZE` or run more iterations to see the effect. It's like there is some limited resource, proportional to memory, which gets used up.

Comment: How many times did you run this experiment?

Comment: @chepner - interesting, I suppose your compiler eliminated the allocations and subsequent processing entirely, since that's way too fast otherwise.

Comment: @juanchopanza - many times, on several boxes!

Comment: Yeah,  I probably shouldn't have commented at all; it's been way too long since I've done anything in C to really know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @BeeOnRope increased loop to 20 - same result, I have ubuntu 16.10 with 4.8.0-27. Increased to 30 - my PC started to swap, same result for 0 or 42.

Comment: Are you running this code in a VM?

Comment: @chepner it [seems that](https://godbolt.org/g/sdxaT5) `clang` can eliminate the buffer writes entirely. I modified the code above to "sink" the buffer to a volatile which fixes this. However, I tested `clang` locally and indeed it seems like it does not exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: @txtechhelp - bare metal.

Comment: Does anything change when you add `free(buf);` after `process`? Or remove optimizations (or use `gcc`)?

Comment: @Slava - interesting. I am on 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0. If you do a `objdump -d -Mintel buffer_weirdness | egrep 'malloc|calloc'` what do you get? I get a single `calloc` call.

Comment: @txtechhelp - if I add `free(buf)` on _each_ iteration, the problem goes away. If I add a `free(buf)` of all the buffers at the end it stays the same. Even in the per iteration-case I can get the problem to return if I use a larger buffer (but it's fussier).

Comment: Search the internet for "data cache hits misses".

Comment: @txtechhelp - it's worth noting though that in the original code, it was several buffers being allocated, and then freed each iteration, so the just freeing everything definitely doesn't avoid it even in read-world code. `gcc` has the same result as `g++` (indeed, the latter is just a thin wrapper around the former). The behavior doesn't occur with `-O` or `Os` or no optmization - but it occurs with `-O2, -O3` and `-Ofast`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - the workload is a streaming one which greatly (1 GB) exceeds the size of all cache levels. In any case, what would explain a massive difference in cache miss rates? Finally, `perf` reports that the (slower timing) zero case has _fewer_ misses: 272 million versus 314 million for the 42 case.

Comment: I also investigated the "might be completely compiled away claim", see my answer.

Answer (score 18):

This seems hard to reproduce, so it's probably compiler/libc specific.

My best guess here:

When you call `malloc`, you get *memory mapped into your process space*, which does *not* mean that the OS has already taken the necessary pages from its pool of free memory, but that it just added entries to some tables.

Now, when you try to access the memory there, your CPU/MMU will raise a fault – and the OS can catch that, and check whether that address belongs to the category "already in the memory space, but not yet actually allocated to the process". If that is the case, the necessary free memory is found and mapped into your process' memory space.

Now, modern OSes often have a built-in option to "zero out" pages prior to (re-)use. If you do that, the `memset(,0,)` operation becomes unnecessary. IN case of POSIX systems, if you use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, the memory gets zeroed out.

In other words, your compiler might have noticed that and completely omitted the `memset(,0,)` when your OS supports that. That means that the moment you write to the pages in `process()` is the first moment they get accessed – and that triggers the "on-the-fly page mapping" mechanism of your OS.

The `memset(,42,)` can of course not be optimized away, so in that case, the pages get actually pre-allocated and you don't see that time spent in the `process()` function.

You should use `/usr/bin/time` to actually compare the whole execution time with the time spent in `process` – my suspicion implies that the time saved in `process` is actually spent in `main`, possibly within kernel context.

**UPDATE**: Tested with the excellent [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/JBdZX7): Yes, with `-O2` and `-O3`, modern gcc simply omits the zero-memsetting (or, rather, simply fuse it into `calloc`, which is `malloc` with zeroing):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  char *p = (char*)malloc(10000);
  if(argc>2) {
    memset(p,42,10000);
  } else {
    memset(p,0,10000);
  }
  return (int)p[190]; // had to add this for the compiler to **not** completely remove all the function body, since it has no effect at all.
}
```

Becomes, for x86_64 on gcc6.3

```
main:
        // store frame state
        push    rbx
        mov     esi, 1
        // put argc in ebx
        mov     ebx, edi
        // Setting up call to calloc (== malloc with internal zeroing)
        mov     edi, 10000
        call    calloc 
        // ebx (==argc) compared to 2 ?
        cmp     ebx, 2
        mov     rcx, rax
        // jump on less/equal to .L2
        jle     .L2
        // if(argc > 2):
        // set up call to memset
        mov     edx, 10000
        mov     esi, 42
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    memset
        mov     rcx, rax
.L2:    //else case
        //notice the distinct lack of memset here!
        // move the value at position rcx (==p)+190 into the "return" register
        movsx   eax, BYTE PTR [rcx+190]
        //restore frame
        pop     rbx
        //return
        ret
```

By the way, if you remove the `return p[190]`,

```
  }
  return 0;
}
```

then there's no reason for the compiler to retain the function body at all – its return value is easily determinable at compile time, and it has no side effect. The whole program then compiles to

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Notice that `A xor A` is `0` for every `A`.

Comment: The 42 case is the faster one, though. The first pass is roughly the same for both; subsequent 0-fills are the slow cases.

Comment: I did note at the very end of my question that the _total_ runtime is comparable. The original issue is that for a benchmark, the timed region is what was important. What's interesting is that `malloc` certainly doesn't always return zeroed memory (you can often observe garbage in there), so the compiler would have to make some kind of leap to know that the `memset` can actually be elided.

Comment: This answer provides a plausible and through analysis. @BeeOnRope the best way to verify it would be to allocate the buffer only once - that is, put the `malloc` outside the loop. I could not reproduce your results but I made once with only *one* allocation and many loops with different  initializations. I observed that the first *of all loops* is the slowest one, almost double the time of all the others. The remaining loops took almost exactly the same amount regardless of the initial value (of `memset`). I agree with the analysis of this answer.

Comment: @A.S.H - why not try with the code as posted and see if you get the same thing? The problem definitely goes away on _subsequent_ `process` calls to the same buffer (they are about as fast as the "fast" cases shown above).

Comment: @BeeOnRope I did that, but as I told I could not reproduce your results (I did not observe any meaningful differences) but your observations might be specific to your platform. Interesting question, though.

Comment: @A.S.H pointed to an online ressource (the godbolt Compiler Explorer) that makes it a lot easier to reproduce things across multiple platforms at an assembler level.

Comment: Thanks. This update further streghthens your answer.

Comment: Yeah I linked this earlier [in a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516240/why-is-writing-to-a-buffer-filled-with-42-way-faster-than-writing-to-a-buffer-of?noredirect=1#comment70238995_41516240) too, showing that `clang` is able to omit substantially the entire `process` method (including all writes to the buffer) unless you "sink" the result somewhere.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - one thing I don't get is why the performance is _initially_ fine, but then slows down on subsequent iterations. I confirm that `gcc` is applying the `calloc` optimization, and so indeed it seems that the `process` routine is taking the page mapping hit - but why is it _sometimes_ fast?

Comment: I'd presume that has to do with your memory usage (seeing that it's very likely that actual access is memory bandwidth-bound); a bit hard to tell without knowing how your system's RAM is set up. Do you perchance have RAM modules of different capacity?

Comment: The reasoning about the ability to elide zeroing by the compiler is wrong - it cannot know what the returned memory will contain. And in fact it did not elide zeroing (from its pov). The first step here should be to disassemble the code (as apparently was done after all) and indeed the use of calloc looks like a valid explanation. As for the rest, OP should profile the code. One can start with 'perf stat' on the binary, but make sure to execute several runs before drawing any conclusions.

Comment: Well, the explanation is indeed incomplete. The reason why the first loop appears faster is that glibc will prefault the memory for the first allocation of this sort.